# Do not interpret Carriage Return (`\0D`) in my terminal

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

I often need to `grep` for a particular expression in a large text file. For some reason the private vendor decide to use `CR` (carriage return, `\0D`) to separate argument on a particular line of the text file.

However the `CR` character gets interpreted by the terminal, making my `grep` or `cat` command pretty much useless.

So how would one display the content on the following file on a terminal (eg. `xterm-256color`).

```
$ hexdump /tmp/bla 
0000000 3031 3030 3020 0d20 3335 310d 3132 3830
0000010 300d 302e 3031 3030 0d30 0a33          
000001c
```

So far I tried without much luck:

```
$ TERM=dumb cat /tmp/bla 
3.010000
```

Comment: Given that it is a large file, you may want to use `less` instead of `cat` when inspecting it. `less` does the `^M` escaping too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU cat has a few options to aid printing files containing such special characters:

```
   -v, --show-nonprinting
          use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

So `cat -v /tmp/bla` should do it in your case. Or perhaps even `-et`, which also prints tabs and line ends in a special way.

Answer (score 1):

Even more useful might be to recognize that the data was hexadecimal, and that 0xd is carriage return (`\r` or `^M`).  There are a couple of ways to work with that:

- the question says *a particular line*, and looking at the dump, this could have been from `script`, where someone was making editing changes to the file.  In that case, one might want to get the final result of the editing changes -- all on one line.  You could use [`col`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/col.1.html) for that, e.g.,

  `col /tmp/bla`

  although `col` is not as powerful as one would like.  (I use a script based on vi-like-emacs manpage filter to get *good* results -- but made a simple script in my response to [Can I programmatically “burn in” ANSI control codes to a file using unix utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269278/can-i-programmatically-burn-in-ansi-control-codes-to-a-file-using-unix-utils) which you might find more useful than `col`).
- then again, OP wanted to treat it as multiple lines.  For that one can do this (translating the carriage returns into newlines):

  `tr '\r' '\n' </tmp/bla`

By the way, carriage return is not an escape sequence (although, like *any* character, one may choose to represent it in C-style "escaped" format).